# SimpleAdapter to populate an ArrayList of bitmaps and textviews

Tags: android, simpleadapter

I want to be able to populate a bitmap and an arraylist stored inside a an SD card.

Now in android developers the String[]from hold the keys which a hashmap loads the item used in each key.

```
SimpleAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to)
```

My problem is more of how would I display an actual Bitmap image since I know of the ["site"](http://devblogs.net/2011/01/04/custom-listview-with-image-using-simpleadapter/) using an example of
HashMap.put(ImageKey, R.id.image) which R.id.image is an integer not a bitmap.

> My question is "How do you load a bitmap inside a SimpleAdapter?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer is that you don't. The longer version is that you need to make your own `BaseAdapter` subclass where you can make the row look like anything that you want.  Have a look at [this chapter](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CEQQFjAA&url=http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf&ei=_kY1T6nHIaec2AWOlcH5AQ&usg=AFQjCNHromPoHbF_bfIsYdgYZjxahjycwA&sig2=_v2F8xoXpXPO-PUyDh2dog) from one of [Commonware's books](http://commonsware.com/books).  It'll take you through the process.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set a viewbinder using api [setViewBinder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html#setViewBinder%28android.widget.SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder%29) .
You will have to implement SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder and you will get callback for every item in [setViewValue](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder.html#setViewValue%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) function. Return true when you have set the data as image and return false for the adapter itself to handle binding